# Showing SVG title tooltip on touchdown event for links

Tags: javascript, css, user-interface, svg, hyperlink

I am trying to create a interactive webpage in SVG format. But on touchscreen devices the title tooltip is not visible.

I have the following code structure:

`<a href="linkto.domain.nl"> <g id="Interactive_element"> <title>Link to domain</title>`
in my SVG file. I want to show the title on touchdown instead of only on hover events? Is it possible to force this with CSS or even JavaScript? Is het better to use custom tooltips (which are less accessible)?
I know that readability of the tooltip is not the best on a mobile device.

Comment: Show us some of your code, what did you tried so far?

Comment: I tried it with CSS: @namespace svg url(http://www.w3.org/2000/svg); svg|a g title { display: block; visibility: visible} but that doesn't work because the title is not really a DOM Element. I want to keep the title element because it is screen reader safe.